# PHP Extract Code out of File

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i have a file (in my case debug.log) and there is a lot of source code from many files in it. I want to extract these lines of code in seperate files.

Structure of my debug.log:

```
#NewFile#path/to/file.php
<?php
class ClassA {
function A() { do smth(); }
}

#NewFile#path/to/nextFile.php
<?php
class ClassA {
function A() { do smth(); }
}

#NewFile#path/to/thirdFile.php
...
```

Now i want to split by #NewFile# and want to save the Content in a new .php File.

This is my code for doing this:

```
$handle = fopen('debug.log', 'r');
$index = 1;
$filename = '/home/myuser/folder/file';

while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    if (strpos($line, '#NewFile#') !== false) {
        $content = file_get_contents($filename . $index . '.php');
        file_put_contents($filename . $index . '.php', $content . $line);
    } else {
        $index++;
    }

}

fclose($handle);
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: So what is not working as you expect?

Comment: Why would there be source code in a log file?...

Comment: Year, well it's kind of a security bug. I think, thats enough information ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own solution for my Problem, that solved it :)

```
$handle = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/debug.log', 'r');
$fileName = '/file';
$dir = '/home/myuser/folder';

while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    if (strpos($line, '#NewFile#') === false) {
        if (file_exists($dir . $fileName)) {
            file_put_contents($dir . $fileName, $line, FILE_APPEND);
        } else {
            preg_match("/(\/.*\/)/", $fileName, $path);
            if (!is_dir($dir . $path[0])) {
                mkdir($dir . $path[0], 0777, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($dir . $fileName, $line);
        }
    } else {
        $fileName = str_replace(".#NewFile#", '', $line);
        $fileName = str_replace("#NewFile#", '', $fileName);
    }

}

fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the fact that a file called `debug.log` seems to contain PHP source (which, no matter how you look at it, is really weird), it's a fairly trivial thing to do:

The simplest way to ***reliably parse*** php files in php is to use [the `token_get_all` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php). In this case, it's a matter of doing something like this:

```
$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents('input_file.php'));
$file = null;
$contents = [];
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    //comment with #NewFile# in there?
    if ($token[0] === T_COMMENT && strstr($token[1]{0}, '#NewFile#')) {
        if ($file) {
            //write code to file
            file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $contents));
        }
        $contents = ['<?php '];
        $file = str_replace('#NewFile#', '', $token[1]);//set file path
    } else {
        //use line numbers as key, append value of current token to the line
        $contents[$token[2]] .= $token[1];
    }
}
//write the last file
if ($file) {
    file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $contents));
}
```

I'm iterating over all the parser tokens. If I encounter a `T_COMMENT` token containing the string `#NewFile#`, I take that as sign that I need to write my current buffer (`$contents` into the file that I last read from the previous comment. After that, I reassign `$file` to point to a new file (again, path and name taken from the comment), and start building the `$contents` buffer again.

After the loop, `$file` and `$contents` will contain all the tokens that should go in the last file, so I just do a quick check (make sure `$file` is set), and write whatever is in the buffer to that file.